# R3 Corda - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must have signed the transaction

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

I have written the following flow to facilitate a transaction between 2 parties - `issuer` and `subscriber`. I have been getting this error at the `Gathering the counterparty's signature.` stage:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must have signed the transaction.`

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must have signed the transaction.
    at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:89) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:64) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at com.sample.flow.sampleFlow$Initiator.call(sampleFlow.kt:106) ~[main/:?]
    at com.sample.flow.sampleFlow$Initiator.call(sampleFlow.kt:30) ~[main/:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
```

My code:
**flow.kt**

```
progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
val participantsParties = sampleState.participants.map { serviceHub.identityService.wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous(it)!! }
val flowSessions = (participantsParties - serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.get(0)).map { initiateFlow(it) }.toSet()
val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, flowSessions, listOf(ourSigningKey), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))
```

I tried the solutions which were presented online that is:

1. to add all parties' sessions as a parameter to `CollectSignaturesFlow`
2. I tried with all constructors of `CollectSignaturesFlow` mentioned on the documentation

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Could someone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is wrong; I will demonstrate using `cordapp-example` flow how 2 (or more) parties sign a transaction:

1. First, your flow should have 2 parts: `Initiator` and `Responder`.
2. Assuming your `issuer` is the party that starts the `Initiator`, then your `subscriber` is the party that runs the `Responder`.
3. `issuer` starts by creating the [transaction](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L73-L75) which identifies the inputs, outputs, command, and required signers.
4. `issuer` [signs](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L85) the transaction, notice how the result is called `partSignedTx`; that's because `subscriber` hasn't signed yet.
5. `issuer` creates a [session with subscriber](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L90) to be used as a communication channel through which they collect the signature of the `subscriber` (you don't create a session with yourself like you did, only with others).
6. `issuer` [requests the signature](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L91) from `subscriber` using that session.
7. `subscriber` inside `Responder` flow [signs the transaction](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L104-L112).
8. `issuer` inside `Initiator` flow [receives the signature](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/01c98454ff8ebf774b8055c70cc0409b72a0e452/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L91). `CollectSignaturesFlow` has a `send` (to send the transaction to be signed) and a `receive` (to receive the signature). Notice how the result is called `fullySignedTx`, because now both `issuer` and `subscriber` signed the transaction.